# Why does Unity ignore normals when calculating backfaces?

Tags: unity, normals

Here's some code to generate a square mesh.

```cs
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[]
{
    new Vector3(x1, y1, z),
    new Vector3(x2, y1, z),
    new Vector3(x2, y2, z),
    new Vector3(x1, y2, z)
};

int[] triangles = new int[]
{
    vertexIndex, vertexIndex + 1, vertexIndex + 2,
    vertexIndex, vertexIndex + 2, vertexIndex + 3
};

Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[]
{
    this.normal, this.normal, this.normal, this.normal
};
```

The resulting mesh looks like this:

[image]

The normals have been set to (0, 0, 1), making the square face in the positive Z direction. I would like them to face in the negative Z direction, so the intuitive solution would be to set the normals to (0, 0, -1), but the result looks like this:

[image]

Despite the normals facing the opposite direction, the face's front is still in the positive Z direction. When viewed from the negative Z direction, the square is invisible due to backside culling.

Why do my normals not affect the directionality of the faces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a decision by Unity, but a standard part of the GPU rendering pipeline. ([See eg. OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling))

The primitive assembly step can be configured to discard faces based on their winding order on the screen, either...

- Culling faces that are wound clockwise (default behaviour in OpenGL)
- Culling faces that are wound counter-clockwise
- Culling neither

This allows culling to work on meshes no matter what weird stuff you might be doing with your normals (eg. whether your normals are in worldspace, object space, or view space, or whether you have multiple normal channels or none at all!), and no matter what camera projection you're using (eg. a perspective camera can technically see parts of meshes with normals pointing "away" along the camera's forward axis when the object is off to the side of the screen), and even if the vertices for a given face all have different normals interpolated across the face.

It's common for 3D authoring tools to pretend this decision is based on normals - but really what they do under the hood is choose which winding order to emit based on the direction of the normal you've specified.

So, if you want to flip the visible facing direction of a generated mesh face, invert the order of its vertex indices.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you. It would be nice if there were more documentation on winding order for Unity users like me who aren't familiar with lower-level rendering.